# MediaQuery.of() Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive

i am searching a way for sizing a element in flutter with the dimensions of the parent widget. How can I do?

I tried with  `MediaQuery.of(WidgetParent)` but this not work.

Thanks

Comment: use `LayoutBuilder`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to size the current widget with respect to the parent widget's dimensions, check this Widget [FractionallySizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `MediaQuery.of(context)` returns the device's screen size, not the parent widget.

You can get the size of the parent widget by using the `LayoutBuilder`.
[YOUTUBE: LayoutBuilder (Flutter Widget of the Week)](https://youtu.be/IYDVcriKjsw)

```dart
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    constraints.maxWidth;

    ...
  }
);
```